# How to return only selected items from Pods Framework?

Tags: podscms

Just started using the PODS framework for Wordpress. Most of it I picked up pretty fast, the rest I'm struggling with. Below is an example of my confusion:

1. I created a custom post (Partner Bio) with auto-templates turned on.
2. I created a pods-template (Bio for Industry) that is sourcing post (Partner Bio).
3. I created another custom post (Industry) with multi-select post-type relationship field to post (Partner Bio).

The issue I'm having is that when I create an instance of post (Industry), then select specific items from that relationship (Partner Bio), (say there are 10, but I chose 3), I'm getting data returned for all of Partner Bio's instead of just the three I chose, so in other words the template pulling data from all Partner Bios regardless of what I choose in the post field drop down.

The template I'm using looks like this:

```
<div>{@post_thumbnail.thumbnail}<br/>
<a href="{@permalink}">{@first_name} {@middle_initial} {@last_name}</a><br/>
{@title_of_partner}<br/>
{@position}<br/>
{@phone}<br/>
<a href="mailto:{@e-mail}">Email {@first_name}</a>
</div>
```

This made me think that when you embed a pod usinge a shortcode, it's not being controlled by the fields selected when you edit your post. So then I tried grabbign the code from the template and then just dropping it in the post, that did not work either.

My goal is to display the block listed above one under another, based on which bios I choose. What am I doing wrong?

**If my example above is confusing, here's a simpler sample illustrating the same issue, this maybe more clear:**

Post A structure/fields:
Name,
Email,
Rel, // Post A's Relationship via post-type to Post B,
Auto templates: on,
Pods Template created: {@name}{@Emal}{@Image}

The issue, is when I create an instance of Post A and select items from the Rel, I'm getting values pulled in from all members of that relationship rather than just what I checked off.

If I turn off auto templates and drop in magic tags into the instance of Post A, I do get back only data for the relationship items I chose but I ge it back in this format:

Name and Name and Name
Emaile and Email and Email

Rather than:

Name
Email

Name
Email
...

Comment: Pods has a really good Slack channel, where you can get help from the Pods team and from Pods community members. I strongly recommend joining pods.io/chat

Comment: @JPollock; agreed, I've been on it for bit and Jim, has helped me out a lot. But I figured I'd drop a beacon here as well.